# Vibration on a tablet running Windows, is it possible on .net?

Tags: .net, windows, desktop-application, tablet, vibration

Is there an API or is there a way to access a vibrate controller of some kind on a Windows based tablet?

As a testing device I got a Lenove Thinkpad 8 which I know it vibrates when the home button is tapped. But I have been trying to find an API exposing this functionality and can't find it.

Does anybody has a suggestion of how to expose it on Windows?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exposure of a `VibrationDevice` to Windows at this point in time (only Windows Phone).